# Does one "laugh out of enjoyment" or "laugh of enjoyment"?

Tags: verbs

Does one "laugh out of enjoyment while watching a movie"? Or does one "laugh from enjoyment"? Or "laugh of enjoyment"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepositions *out of*, *from*, and *of* are all used indicate the source or cause of something. You could justify using any of them. However, I don't think they are equal.

- *laugh of enjoyment* - This is probably the weakest choice due to numerous uses of the word *of*. Since *of* can also indicate possession, composition, association, etc., it takes a bit more processing to determine the meaning of the phrase.
- *laugh from enjoyment* - This works well. It is immediately clear that the source of the laugh is enjoyment.
- *laugh out of enjoyment* - This is a very good phrase. It indicates that enjoyment is the source of the laugh. Also the phrase *out of* implies that the enjoyment is internal and the laugh is the external result of that enjoyment.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *to laugh* is used (at least in writing) with all of these prepositions. Using this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=to+laugh+out+of%2Cto+laugh+from%2Cto+laugh+of+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), you can see that *to laugh from* and *to laugh out of* are more common:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=to%20laugh%20out%20of%2Cto%20laugh%20from%2Cto%20laugh%20of&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000

Some examples of both, as given in Google Books, are:

**to laugh out of**:

> My first instinct was to laugh out of appreciation for his planning.
>
> Only to laugh out of spite, only to laugh.

**to laugh from**:

> Most adults have lost, too, the ability to laugh from sheer happiness;
>
> Humanity ceased to laugh from the fourth century on
>
> When you beg them to imagine away every feeling of laughter and of tendency to laugh from their consciousness of the ludicrousness of an object

As you can see, using *from* has more interpretations such as being used to denote a point in time. However, both *out of* and *from* can be used to denote why a person is laughing. In context, either would be acceptable (a person would correctly interpret *from* or *out of* to give the reason for laughing).